# app.launchURL('http://www.google.com',false); not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, pdf-generation, itext

I have a pdf containing a dropdown in it. This `pdf` is displayed on browser. On selecting any value from the dropdown I need to redirect the browser to `http://www.google.com`. I have used `iTextSharp` for this.

The code written for redirection is 
    app.launchURL('http://www.google.com',false);

This is working as expected in *IE* and *Firefox* but is not in *Chrome*, any idea??

Comment: Does this problem occur only when using the integrated PDF viewer of Chrome? Or also when switching that off and relying on the Adobe plugin? The PDF viewer built into Chrome has some restrictions, and you may just have found one.

Comment: Its working if I use Adobe PDF Viewer

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable the Chrome PDF viewer and use the Adobe Reader plugin instead.

To disable the Chrome PDF Viewer go to chrome://plugins/ in a new Chrome tab, search the plugin, and click Disable. In the same list you should find the Adobe Reader plugin, which must be Enabled (or any other PDF viewer plugin like Foxit Reader Plugin).

Then you should be able to follow PDF document links.

Comment: The code "app.launchURL('http://www.google.com',false);" is written on the server side, how can I ask end user to disable Chrome PDF viewer and use Adobe Reader plugin, if he is using Chrome as user agent.

Comment: Put a paragraph to that effect into the PDF.